# Cordova/Phonegap Database operation inside for loop

Tags: database, cordova, sqlite

I have to do a loop through some SELECT results. Inside this loop I need to perform an UPDATE and an INSERT transactions.

The problem is that the SQL Transactions are asynchronous and slow, therefore the loop ends before the SQL operations are executed, here is how my code works:

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...', [], 
    function(tx, results){
        for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++){
            var id = results.rows.item(i).id;

            tx.executeSql('UPDATE ... SET ...=... WHERE id="'+ id +'";', [], 
                function(tx, results){
                    console.log("update ok");
                }, function(){
                    console.error("Function ERROR");
            });

            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ... (...) VALUES (...,"'+ id +'",...)', [], 
                function(tx, results){  
                        console.log("insert ok");
                }, function(){
                console.error("Function ERROR");
            });                                             
        }
    }, function(){
        console.error("Function ERROR");
});
```

The for loop runs faster than the DB operations and all uptades and inserts end up using the last 'i' of the iteration. I tried to put the insert inside the update callback, but still got the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...', [], 
    function(tx, results){
        for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++){
            var id = results.rows.item(i).id;
            var transaction = function(valueID){
                tx.executeSql('UPDATE ... SET ...=... WHERE id="'+ id +'";', [], 
                    function(tx, results){
                        console.log("update ok");
                    }, function(){
                        console.error("Function ERROR");
                });

                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ... (...) VALUES (...,"'+ id +'",...)', [], 
                    function(tx, results){  
                            console.log("insert ok");
                    }, function(){
                    console.error("Function ERROR");
                });   
            }(id)               
        }
    }, function(){
        console.error("Function ERROR");
});
```

Had to wrap it inside a function to get the values right.

Hope it helps someone else. o/